# Apex design pattern question

Tags: apex

I have a wrapper class

** EDIT START ****

Note: This is just pseudo code to help illustrate the problem.

```
public with sharing class TestStrategy {

List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
public class A{
    Integer accountNumber;
    String accountName;
    String aValue1;
    String aValue2;
}
public class B{
    Integer accountNumber;
    String accountName;
    String bValue1;
    String bValue2;
}
public class C{
    Integer accountNumber;
    String accountName;
    String cValue1;
    String cValue2;
}
public class Wrapper{
    public List<A> firstList;
    public List<B> secondList;
    public List<C> thirdList;

}

public static void parse(json){
    Wrapper w = new Wrapper();
    w = (Wrapper)JSON.deserialize(json, Wrapper.class);
    //now onto processing the wrapper for all three lists

    for (A a1: w.firstList){
        Account ax = new Account();
        ax.Name = a1.accountName;
        ax.accountNumber = a1.accountNumber;
        ax.aValue1 = 'aaa'
        ax.aValue2 = 'a123';
        acctList.add(ax);   
    }

    for (B b1: w.secondList){
        Account ax = new Account();
        //can these 2 lines not be repeated?
        ax.Name = b1.accountName;
        ax.accountNumber = b1.accountNumber;
        ax.bValue1 = 'bbb'
        ax.bValue2 = 'b123'
        acctList.add(ax);   
    }
    for (C c1: w.thirdList){
        Account ax = new Account();
        //can these 2 lines not be repeated?
        ax.Name = c1.accountName;
        ax.accountNumber = c1.accountNumber;
        ax.cValue1 = 'ccc'
        ax.cValue2 = 'c123'
        acctList.add(ax);   
    }

}
```

}

Assume that aValue1, aValue2, bValue1, bValue2, cValue1, cValue2 are custom fields on the Account object

Assume Name and AccountNumber are standard fields on the Account Object

Now, firstList, secondList and thirdList are going to be populated into the Account Object and there are a set of common fields in all these list and there are some unique custom field that pertain specifically to these lists as well

Is there any design pattern that I can follow to populate to these common fields versus having to repeat the population of common fields in all 3 methods when I try to load data from each of them into Account. Also, do I have to use 3 loops (as in my case my wrapper has more objects) or is there a better way to handle this data population.

*** EDIT COMPLETE *** Hopefully, this makes more sense now.

Please advise.

Thx.

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me: e.g. lists in the wrapper but "into the Account Object" (singular) in the text.

Comment: I agree with Keith C here, your description is way too vague to be able to make any real suggestions here.

Comment: Some code, even if it doesn't compile, could go a long way towards helping us understand what you're looking for here.

Comment: @KeithC  have added the code now

Comment: @DavidSchach why is this still put on hold? I made edits to the original post to help illustrate the issue

Answer (score 1):

On the question of repeating the lines, Apex class fields can't be accessed by a name string so you are stuck with hard coded lines of code. But you can deserialize into a map where values can be accessed by a name string and SObject fields can be accessed by a name string too.

I'm still not too clear what optimisation/improvement you are looking for, but the code could look more line this:

```
public with sharing class TestStrategy {

    private static final Map<String, String> FIRST_FIELD_MAP = new Map<String, String>{
        'accountName' => 'Name',
        'accountNumber' => 'AccountNumber',
        'aValue1' => 'Value1__c',
        'aValue2' => 'Value2__c'
    };

    private static final Map<String, String> SECOND_FIELD_MAP ...

    private static final Map<String, String> THIRD_FIELD_MAP ...

    public class Wrapper {
        public List<Map<String, Object>> firstList;
        public List<Map<String, Object>> secondList;
        public List<Map<String, Object>> thirdList;
    }

    public static List<Account> parse(String jsonString) {

        Wrapper w = (Wrapper) JSON.deserialize(jsonString, Wrapper.class);

        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
        copyItems(w.firstList, accounts, FIRST_FIELD_MAP);
        copyItems(w.secondList, accounts, SECOND_FIELD_MAP);
        copyItems(w.thirdList, accounts, THIRD_FIELD_MAP);
        return accounts;
    }

    private static void copyItems(
            List<Map<String, Object>> maps,
            List<Account> accounts,
            Map<String, String> fm
            ) {
        for (Map<String, Object> m : maps) {
            accounts.add(copyFields(m, new Account(), fm));
        }
    }

    private static Account copyFields(
            Map<String, Object> m,
            Account a,
            Map<String, String> fm
            ) {
        for (String fromField : fm.keySet()) {
            String toField = fm.get(fromField);
            a.put(toField, m.get(fromField));
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```